# View Binding gives a message but everything works

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

[image]

I got a problem it says System.Object but when I run the program , everything is as it should be with a good view

```xml
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

```cs
public class MainViewModel :ObservableObject
{
    private object _currentView;
    public HomeViewModel HomeVm { get; set; }

    public object CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        HomeVm = new HomeViewModel();
        CurrentView = HomeVm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your DataTemplate?

```
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel}">
        <view/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to "Enable project code" on view desginer.
[image]